# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'X' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I had an existing method to manipulate and add properties to an object as below;

```
result.sectionGroupOrder = newOrder;
result.sectionGroups[group.name] = group;
result.sectionGroups['My Component'].component = MyComponent;
```

Above works fine for the first time.
However, when I tried leveraging the same method passing in the result of useSelector (I have used Redux Toolkit)

```
const data = useSelector(state => state.formData.data);
```

In the reducer, I have

```
setFormData: (state, {
    payload
}) => {
    setData(state, payload);
},
```

So the moment I have below i.e. assign data to result, I start seeing errors for the below statements
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'X' of object '#'

```
result = data; // Existing data that was set to Redux state
result.sectionGroupOrder = newOrder;
result.sectionGroups[group.name] = group;
result.sectionGroups['My Component'].component = MyComponent;
```

I assume this would fix if I use Object.assign(), but I want to avoid doing that, since there are multiple places to fix (only few update lines shown above).
So is there a global way of fixing this issue, since I do not want to update in multiple places

Comment: Remember to show the full error.

Comment: You are omitting too many details here for anyone to really understand what you are doing. Please provide something that really follows along all method calls.  It's not obvious in any way where you are actually doing those mutations.

Comment: @phry : So I am getting some API response and kind of massaging that for my internal UI components. The issue (Cannot assign to read only property 'X' ) started coming the moment I had this transformed response go through Redux Toolkit states. So the error does not come for the first run, but for subsequent runs when I do result = data;...where data is actually existing data that was saved to Redux state and then when mutations are run on that existing data.

Comment: Hope the above helps in understanding the issue

Comment: You haven't updated any code examples, so it's still hard to understand. You should only get these errors if you try to change state outside a reducer. Calling a method that does the change from within a reducer is fine, calling it from outside a reducer is not.